# "Correct" way to describe "looking at someone with new eyes" or similar?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

I'm not a native English-speaker, so I'm not sure how to "correctly" phrase the following...

When you learn something new about a person, than makes you look at him "with new eyes" - and perhaps re-evaluate his previous actions (or rather your interpretation of them... a revelation that "tilts your world".

I have a few suggestions myself, but I don't know which one(s) - if any - would be "correct" English:

- Seeing NN with new eyes.
- Seeing NN with different eyes.
- Seeing NN in a new light.
- Seeing NN in a different light.
- Seeing NN with open (or perhaps "opened") eyes.
- *...any other that springs to mind?*

PS: I would prefer something with "eyes" - unless that would be totally non-English...

Comment: Phrases like "I saw her in a totally new light" and "My eyes had been opened" are idiomatic but that doesn't mean they are more "correct". If you want to invent your own phrase using "with new eyes" then that is fine and may even give more impact to the emotion you're trying to convey. For example, suppose you literally felt like you'd been given a new pair of eyes and that it enabled you to see the person you thought you knew as if it was first time seeing her in your life. Make this into a phrase in your writing. If you say instead "I saw her in a new light" then of course it sounds routine.

Comment: I'm really looking for the "most correct" *existing* English phrase - if I invent something, that's accidental and because I don't know any better...

Comment: "In a new light" is probably what you're trying to go for. "My eyes had been opened" implies that you had a misunderstanding and now you see something differently. And the idea of "correctness" here doesn't exist. You can at best find the most commonly used phrase, but that doesn't mean it's correct, especially if you are writing something where you want to convey a certain emotion.

Answer (score 3):

Look "with new eyes" - could be replaced with (rephrased to):

> - [**change of opinion**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/reevaluate?family=reevALUATE)
> - **reconsider**/rethink, reevaluate
> - give new consideration to
> - revise or renew one's assessment
> - etc.